# Can Partner Org with LMA be merged with Salescloud org?

Tags: appexchange, isv

I helped a company become a Salesforce ISV Partner with a Security Approved Managed Package. In the process of becoming a Partner, Salesforce assigned them a Partner Business Org (PBO) where the Licence Management App is installed, and where we connected our Package (PBO is the DevHub).

While setting up the Listing and AppExchange Lead routing the Partner realized the PBO org is NOT the org where they have their Salescloud in and normally do Lead management.

I asked Salesforce in Case #44405532 and I am asking here:

**Can a production org be merged with a PBO org? If not what is the best mitigation?**

Comment: I know we have sales cloud licences in the same org that LMA is setup in, and we did move LMA at one point from a PBO to the current one, but I don't know if our current one is a second PBO that we got for a separate legal entitiy, or if it started life as a sales cloud org. I've got a feeling it was a PBO and we migrated LMA.

Comment: We cannot move the PBO to CRM org because the DevHub cannot be moved. And moving thei business org is also not feasable.

Comment: You can now move packages from one dev hub to another, so why can't you "move" your dev hub? Is this more about the scratch org management limits?

Comment: @PhilW is that desribed anyway (official documents)? You mean we should abandon the new PBO and move DevHub, Lma, Packages etcs into the original CRM org?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting. Yes, this is [documented officially](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_package_transfer.htm), though still marked as a beta for some reason.

Comment: And how would all the other apps and their data be "migrated over": LMA, COA, Package and Version records? Did you ever do this process @PhilW?

Comment: Robert, no I didn't do this. It's troublesome that your customer didn't think to point out to Salesforce that there was an existing CRM org for their business; the natural approach would be to have simply made that the PBO. I'm sure there must be a process. Perhaps Salesforce can still can the new PBO and upcycle the CRM org to be the PBO... as long as any specific necessary details are transferred as part of that process. Very much one for Salesforce Support to deal with I think. Good luck!